# Eye Blinking Detection

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

Some warnings appear in terminal during running:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed(s>=0) in setSize, file /home/me/opencv2.4/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 116

The program compiled without error and executes, the problem is the eye ROI size changes when user moves closer/farther away from webcam, due to the changing of size, the warning appears. I managed to solve these warnings by setting the eye ROI size equal to my eye template size. However, it ends up the program fails to classify user's eyes open/close because the `minVal` obtained is `0`. The method used is OpenCV [Template Matching](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html). Alternatively, I fix my distance from webcam and fix the eye template size could avoid the warning. Every time warning appears, the program fails to classify open/close eyes. The program doesn't work effectively because sometimes it mistakenly classifies the open eyes as closed and vice versa.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any alternative to identify open and close eyes other than template matching?
2. Any ideas how to improve the program in classification of blinking?
3. Any working example that you know in opencv C/C++ API can classify open and close eyes and count accurately the blinking times?

   ```
    static CvMemStorage* storage = 0;  
    // Create a new Haar classifier  
    static CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade = 0;  
    // Function prototype for detecting and drawing an object from an image  
    bool detect_and_draw( IplImage* image ,CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade);  

    const char *cascade_name[1]={"eyes.xml"};  
    cv::Mat roiImg;  
    int threshold_value = 200;  
    int threshold_type = 3;;  
    int const max_value = 255;  
    int const max_type = 4;  
    int const max_BINARY_value = 255;  
    int hough_thr = 35;  
    cv::Mat src_gray, dst;  
    using namespace cv;  
    Mat img1; Mat img2; Mat templ; Mat result;  
    const char* image_window = "Source Image";  
    const char* result_window = "Result window";  
    int match_method=0;  
    int max_Trackbar = 5;  
    int eye_open=0;  
    int eye_close=0;  

    //Matching with 2 images ,eye closed or open  
    void MatchingMethod(cv::Mat templ,int id )  
    {  
     /// Source image to display  
     cv::Mat img_display;  
     roiImg.copyTo( img_display );  
     /// Create the result matrix  
     int result_cols = roiImg.cols - templ.cols + 1;  
     int result_rows = roiImg.rows - templ.rows + 1;  
     result.create( result_cols, result_rows, CV_32FC1 );  
     /// Do the Matching and Normalize  
     cv::matchTemplate( roiImg, templ, result, match_method );  
     cv::normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );  
     /// Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc  
     double minVal; double maxVal; Point minLoc; Point maxLoc;  
     cv::Point matchLoc;  
     cv::minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat() );  
     ///Justing checkin the match template value reaching the threashold  
     if(id == 0 && (minVal < 0))  
         {  
         eye_open=eye_open+1;  
         if(eye_open == 1)  
              {  
              std::cout<<"Eye Open"<<std::endl;  
              eye_open=0;  
              eye_close=0;  
              }  
         }  
      else if(id == 1 && (minVal < 0))  
         eye_close=eye_close+1;  
         if(eye_close == 1)  
              {  
              std::cout<<"Eye Closed"<<std::endl;  
              eye_close=0;  
              system("python send_arduino.py");  
              }  
     /// For SQDIFF and SQDIFF_NORMED, the best matches are lower values. For all the other methods, the higher the better  
     if( match_method == CV_TM_SQDIFF || match_method == CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED )  
      { matchLoc = minLoc; }  
     else  
      { matchLoc = maxLoc; }  
     /// Show me what you got  
     cv::rectangle( img_display, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols , matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0 );  
     cv::rectangle( result, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols , matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0 );  
     cv::imshow( image_window, img_display );  
     cv::imshow( result_window, result );  
     return;  
    }  
    void detect_blink(cv::Mat roi)  
    {  
         try  
         {        
         MatchingMethod(img1,0);  
          MatchingMethod(img2,1);  
         }  
         catch( cv::Exception& e )  
         {  
              std::cout<<"An exception occued"<<std::endl;  
         }  
    }  
    // Main function, defines the entry point for the program.  
    int main( int argc, char** argv )  
    {  
      if(argc <= 1)  
         {  
         std::cout<<"\n Help "<<std::endl;  
         std::cout<<"\n ------------------------------------\n"<<std::endl;  
         std::cout<<"./blink_detect open_eye.jpg close_eye.jpg\n"<<std::endl;  
        std::cout<<"Eg :: ./blink_detect 2.jpg 3.jpg\n"<<std::endl;  
         std::cout<<"\n ------------------------------------\n"<<std::endl;  
         exit(0);  
         }  
      // Structure for getting video from camera or avi  
      CvCapture* capture = 0;  
      // Images to capture the frame from video or camera or from file  
      IplImage *frame, *frame_copy = 0;  
      // Used for calculations  
      int optlen = strlen("--cascade=");  
      // Input file name for avi or image file.  
      const char* input_name;  
       img1 = imread( argv[1], 1 );  
       img2 = imread( argv[2], 1 );  
      // Load the HaarClassifierCascade  
       /// Create windows  
       cv::namedWindow( image_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );  
       cv::namedWindow( result_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );  
      // Allocate the memory storage  
      storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);  
      capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( 0);  
      // Create a new named window with title: result  
      cvNamedWindow( "original_frame", 1 );  
      // If loaded succesfully, then:  
      if( capture )  
      {  
        // Capture from the camera.  
        for(;;)  
        {  
          // Capture the frame and load it in IplImage  
          if( !cvGrabFrame( capture ))  
            break;  
          frame = cvRetrieveFrame( capture );  
          // If the frame does not exist, quit the loop  
          if( !frame )  
            break;  
          // Allocate framecopy as the same size of the frame  
          if( !frame_copy )  
            frame_copy = cvCreateImage( cvSize(frame->width,frame->height),  
                          IPL_DEPTH_8U, frame->nChannels );  
          // Check the origin of image. If top left, copy the image frame to frame_copy.   
          if( frame->origin == IPL_ORIGIN_TL )  
            cvCopy( frame, frame_copy, 0 );  
          // Else flip and copy the image  
              for(int i=0;i<1;i++)  
              {  
           cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad( cascade_name[i], 0, 0, 0 );  
           // Check whether the cascade has loaded successfully. Else report and error and quit  
           if( !cascade )  
                {  
                   fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: Could not load classifier cascade\n" );  
                   return -1;  
                }  
          // Call the function to detect and draw the face  
               if(detect_and_draw(frame_copy,cascade))  
              {  
                   std::cout<<"Detected"<<std::endl;  
              }                                
              }  
          // Wait for a while before proceeding to the next frame  
          if( cvWaitKey( 1 ) >= 0 )  
           break;  
       }  
        // Release the images, and capture memory  
        cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade(&cascade);  
        cvReleaseImage( &frame_copy );  
        cvReleaseCapture( &capture );  
        cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage);  
      }  
     return 0;  
    }  
    // Function to detect and draw any faces that is present in an image  
    bool detect_and_draw( IplImage* img,CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade )  
    {  
      int scale = 1;  
      // Create a new image based on the input image  
      IplImage* temp = cvCreateImage( cvSize(img->width/scale,img->height/scale), 8, 3 );  
      // Create two points to represent the face locations  
      CvPoint pt1, pt2;  
      int i;  
      // Clear the memory storage which was used before  
      cvClearMemStorage( storage );  
      // Find whether the cascade is loaded, to find the faces. If yes, then:  
      if( cascade )  
      {  
        // There can be more than one face in an image. So create a growable sequence of faces.  
        // Detect the objects and store them in the sequence  
        CvSeq* faces = cvHaarDetectObjects( img, cascade, storage,  
                          1.1, 8, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING,  
                          cvSize(40, 40) );  
        // Loop the number of faces found.  
        for( i = 0; i < (faces ? faces->total : 0); i++ )  
        {  
          // Create a new rectangle for drawing the face  
          CvRect* r = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem( faces, i );  
          // Find the dimensions of the face,and scale it if necessary  
          pt1.x = r->x*scale;  
          pt2.x = (r->x+r->width)*scale;  
          pt1.y = r->y*scale;  
          pt2.y = (r->y+r->height)*scale;  
          // Draw the rectangle in the input image  
          cvRectangle( img, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(255,0,0), 3, 8, 0 );  
          cv::Mat image(img);  
          cv::Rect rect;  
          rect = cv::Rect(pt1.x,pt1.y,(pt2.x-pt1.x),(pt2.y-pt1.y));  
          roiImg = image(rect);  
            cv::imshow("roi",roiImg);       
    ///Send to arduino  
          detect_blink(roiImg);  
        }  
      }  

      cvShowImage( "original_frame", img );  
      if(i > 0)  
              return 1;  
         else  
              return 0;  

      cvReleaseImage( &temp );  
    }
   ```

Reference:
[Website referred](http://www.technolabsz.com/2013/05/eye-blink-detection-using-opencv-in.html)

Comment: can you be more specific ? where exactly you get those warnings ?

Comment: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed(s>=0) in setSize, file /home/me/opencv2.4/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 116. (Warning shows in terminal)